# How to prevent overlay / header from displaying a second time on site

Tags: javascript, html, css

my portfolio opens with a welcome overlay, which when scrolled upon gets rid of the overlay by reducing height to "0%" and displays my work. The problem is every time I return to the main page (which is also my work page) the overlay header loads again which I dont want. How can I stop it from loading again?

HTML

```
<section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="homeContainer">
      <img id="logo" src="images/00 - Logo/Logo.png">
      <h1 id="navTitle">Hi, my name is Menachem Polonsky.</h1>
      <p id="navBody">Are you ready for an adventure?</p>
      <div id="homeLine"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
 .home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .8s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(47.77deg, #05070F 27.82%, #122837 56.13%, #567582 100%);
}
```

JS

```
    // Close Home

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.body.scrollBottom > 1) {
    document.getElementById("home").style.height = "0%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) - [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean value in `localStorage` to achieve this.

```
    let res = localStorage.getItem("overlay");
    if (res == null || res === false) {
        // show overlay here
        console.log('setting overlay');
        localStorage.setItem("overlay", true);
    } else { return; }
```

You may add these to your `scrollFunction()`

Comment: You need to add it to top of your function, above the `if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.body.scrollBottom > 1) {` statement

Answer (score 0):

Rather than measuring how far the user has scrolled from the top of the page, I would activate the function at the first sign that the user scrolled with jQuery. For example:

```
var firstScroll = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ( !firstScroll ) {
      hideWelcomeMessage();
  }
});

function hideWelcomeMessage() {

    firstScroll = true;        

    // Your code here
    document.getElementById("home").style.height = "0%";
}
```

I hope this helps!